# Turn a float type number into percentage by row on a Data Frame- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hope you are doing ok. I have the following DataFrame:

| Date | Income_type | Mike | Joan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/10/31 | Salary | 25 | 32 |
| 2021/10/31 | Investments | 10 | 9 |
| 2021/10/31 | Investments/Salary | 0,4 | 0,28 |
| 2021/09/30 | Salary | 30 | 36 |
| 2021/09/30 | Investments | 15 | 6 |
| 2021/09/30 | Investments/Salary | 0,5 | 0,16 |

And I want to turn the Investments /Salary row numbers into a percentage, like this:

| Date | Income_type | Mike | Joan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/10/31 | Salary | 25 | 32 |
| 2021/10/31 | Investments | 10 | 9 |
| 2021/10/31 | Investments/Salary | 40% | 28% |
| 2021/09/30 | Salary | 30 | 36 |
| 2021/09/30 | Investments | 15 | 6 |
| 2021/09/30 | Investments/Salary | 50% | 16% |

I have tried the following but it hasn't worked:

```
df['Mike'] = np.where(df['Income_type']=='Investments/salary',df['Mike'].astype(float).map(lambda n: '{:.2%}'.format(n)),df['Mike'])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Should `0,10` be `100%` or `10%`?

Comment: It should be 10%

Comment: But `0,9` should be `90%`, right?

Comment: Yes, it is like multyplying the float by a 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
df.update(
    df.loc[df.Income_type =='Investments/Salary'][['Mike','Jordan']]\
        .replace(to_replace =',', value = '.', regex = True).astype(float)
        )

df.update(df.loc[df.Income_type =='Investments/Salary']['Mike'].map("{:.2%}".format))
df.update(df.loc[df.Income_type =='Investments/Salary']['Jordan'].map("{:.2%}".format))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  lambda  functions like  this.  I tested it  with  synthetic data   :

```
df.Mike = df.Mike.astype(float)

def make_percentage(x):
    if  float(x)<1:
        return str(float(x)*100)+'%'
    else: return x
df.Mike = df.Mike.apply(lambda x: make_percentage(x))
```